# container doesnt work using inside of a simple controller class in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

My Error:

```
> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
> Agc\ManagerBundle\Lib\grafica::__construct() must implement interface
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface, none given,
> called in
> C:\wamp\www\galileo\src\Agc\BackendBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php
> on line 20 and defined in
> C:\wamp\www\galileo\src\Agc\ManagerBundle\Lib\grafica.php line 10
```

My class grafica:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
/**
 * @Route(service="srv_grafica")
 */
class grafica
{
    private $container, $conn, $bdnmgi;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->conn = $this->getConn();
        $this->bdnmgi = $this->getBd();
    }

    public function getConn(){
        return $this->container->get('database_connection');
    }
    public function getBd(){
        return $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getAdministracion()->getNombreEsquemamgi();
    }
}
```

\ManagerBundle\Resources\config\services.yml

```
services:
    srv_grafica:
        class: Agc\ManagerBundle\Lib\grafica
        arguments:
            - '@service_container'
```

My DefaultController:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function dashboardAction(Request $peticion)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('customer_1');
        $user= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $esquema = $user->getAdministracion()->getNombreEsquemamgi();
        var_dump($esquema);
        $grafica = new grafica();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling

```
$grafica = new grafica();
```

And this class requires `ContainerInterface` argument in constructor. To fix this you need to change this line to:

```
$grafica = new grafica($this->container);
```

Note, that your code is not written in Symfony way. To do this properly you should define your `grafica` [class as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) and you should not inject whole container, just inject classes you need